# TFS - Bugs Process Template - Newly added states not available

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I downloaded the Process Template.

updated the Bugs process template by adding these new states and State transitions for it.

Newly added states

"Merged to UAT"
"Released to UAT"
"Merged to Trunk"
"Released to PROD"

```html
<STATE value="New">
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</STATE>
<STATE value="Active">
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</STATE>
<STATE value="Resolved">
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
   <EMPTY/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</STATE>
<STATE value="Closed"/>
<STATE value="Merged to UAT"/>
<STATE value="Released to UAT"/>
<STATE value="Merged to Trunk"/>
<STATE value="Released to PROD"/>
```

And i have added new State Transitions

```html
<TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="Merged to UAT">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Merged to UAT"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Merged to UAT" to="Released to UAT">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Released to UAT"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Merged to UAT" to="Closed">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Not Releasing to Prod"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Released to UAT" to="Merged to Trunk">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Merged to Trunk"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Released to UAT" to="Closed">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Not releasing to PROD"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Merged to Trunk" to="Closed">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Not Releasing to Prod"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Merged to Trunk" to="Released to PROD">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Released to PROD"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
<TRANSITION from="Released to PROD" to="Closed">
 <REASONS>
  <DEFAULTREASON value="Approved in Prod"/>
 </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
  <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
   <COPY from="currentuser"/>
  </FIELD>
 </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Was able to import the Template successfully.

But even after added these , I do not see the States available for Transition on the Bugs.

I have restarted Visual studio and also made sure that i disconnect and reconnect with TFS thinking its a caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. We cannot update the Process Template on an existing Project.

I Created a new Project in the collection and i saw the new Process Template to be associated. Once the new Project created with the newly built process template all the states were available on it.

Another option is as stated in this link. (**Have not tried it yet)

https://adamstephensen.com/2013/08/01/adding-a-testing-column-to-your-tfs-2012-task-board/